# Alternatives to select() on client side

Tags: c, sockets, posix-select

Is there an alternative to `select()` for the client side of a TCP non-blocking socket connection?

`select()` is mainly for multiple connections, but my client only has a single connection. As a result, I asked myself if there is an alternative function to recognise I/O on a single socket. That would probably be faster and I wouldn't need all the `fd_set` handling.

Comment: maybe you can have a thread reading and you just have to check a special value or something like that

Comment: If you don't want to poll actively through `select`/`poll`/etc., then you could use signals with a `SIGIO` signal handler. Or use a thread for the connection, and blocking sockets in the thread.

Comment: If you've only got a single file descriptor to monitor, you could use non-blocking `read()` calls — assuming it is a TCP socket and not a UDP socket.  The non-blocking `read()` would return immediately if there was no data to read, and your program would get on with life.  If you want it to block, just use `read()`.  You would use `fcntl()` to set the non-blocking attribute on the file descriptor.

Answer (score 2):

Select() helps you monitor both read and write events (and exception events) in one shot, so it does make things scalable rather than the application having to check (since it is non-blocking). You probably should clarify what is your end design objective. Of course, as someone mentioned, having two threads, one for read and write might do the same thing. In fact, if you have a higher workload, you can go beyond two and actually keep a pool of threads.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `select()` in the client, and it will not be faster if you're using `select` for just one socket.

By the way `select()` isn't for multiple connections ... in real-world, due to its performance issues. Just for your information, take a look at `/dev/poll`/`epoll()`/`kqueue()`  and `io completion port` for Windows.